# Send Acknowledge Email To Users After Form Submittal

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I want to send acknowledge email to users once they contact me via my website contact form.

I am able to do it in PHP by using this code:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
$replymsg = "Thank you for your interest. Our team will contact you soon";
mail($email, $subject, $replymsg, $headers);
```

How can I do the same thing using the CodeIgniter framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the CI email class. Here is the [documentation](http://userguides.ellislab.com/codeigniter/libraries/email.html) please visit it so you can use the values set in your `$headers` variable. I do not know them so I just didn't put them in below code.

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to($to);
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($message);
$this->email->send();

$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to($email);
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message("Thank you for your interest. Our team will contact you soon");
$this->email->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter has a pretty nice email library that's a little nicer to work with than PHP's `mail` function although for a simple email like the one in your example there's not much of a difference.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html